# Encrypt a textbox value with adding character to each letters

Tags: c#

How can i encrypt a textbox with adding example char(65) to each of its containing characters??

Example if my textbox contains word hello, i want to add H+char(65),e+char(67)..and so on.

I want to succeed some kind of serial key.

I'm using this code for bring into my textbox a random value.

```
        Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
        string GuidString = Convert.ToBase64String(g.ToByteArray());
        GuidString = GuidString.Replace("=", "");
        GuidString = GuidString.Replace("+", "");
        GuidString = GuidString.Replace("/", "");
        textBox1.Text = GuidString;
```

So from this code, i'm my client will take this serial key.U3h2FfzjSkeS47XFSyZmQ

So i want to make an exe which will be able to transform this serial key to other characters.
So if my client will ask me for serial key he must give me this serial which already exe gave him and to send him the transformed one which when it will paste it into his exe to be register his product.

Comment: It's not really clear how your GUID and the user entered text come together. Can you add a complete example of the input and desired output? Do you want to be able to decrypt the generated result or do you just want to randomize a serial key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate through every string character and add the corresponding value to it. You can simply add a number and then cast the value to char. I hope it will not handle any cryptography related functionality in your project.

```
string stringToEncode = "Hello";
string encodedString = "";

for (int i = 0; i < stringToEncode.Length; i++)
    encodedString += (char)(stringToEncode[i] + 65);
```

Serial codes consist mainly of digits, upper and lower case letters and sometimes dashes. It means the resulting value of each character must fall into one of the specified ranges according to the ASCII table:

- dash - 45
- digits - [48 - 57]
- upper case letters - [65, 90]
- lower case letters - [97, 122]

Solution does not seem elegant, but you have to implement your own mapping for characters (0 stands for a, 1 stands for b ... 25 stands for z and so on) and then map it to ASCII [character codes](http://ascii.cl/), rather than checking whether for any pair of characters A and B (A + B) has a valid value. This way your + operation followed by % [length of the alphabet] will always produce a valid value since it will be a [XOR operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher)

Comment: I need something like that. But i want avoid all strange characters *-{}[] and so on.Or if i can take only letters